# c++ overload between "str" and const char[N]?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to overload such calls?

```
f("st");//variant 1
struct Foo { char buf[3]; Foo() { strcpy(buf, "aa"); } };
const Foo foo;
f(foo.buf);//variant 2
```

In both cases `typeid` give the same type,
is any variant to distinguish between two calls of `f` above,
and have two variants of `f`? I try `std::is_rvalue_reference` but without success.

Comment: `"st"` is of type `const char[N]`.

Comment: A string literal is `const char[N]` which is different from `char[N]`.

Comment: @n.m. `foo` may be `const` modified as well.

Comment: I doubt there is any way you can achieve that.

Comment: If both are `const char[N]`, there's no way. Why would you want to distinguish them?

Comment: I want to check length of string at runtime with static_assert if input argument literal, and at runtime if input argument is const array.

Comment: You can't distinguish values created from literals from values created in a different manner.

Comment: But in the first case it has no name, and in the second it has, may be it is possible to use this, some rvalue, lvalue magic?

Comment: @user1244932 string-literal has static storage duration. It's not rvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If object of type `Foo` is not const object, that you can use something like

```
template<size_t N>
void f(const char(&a)[N])
{
   std::cout << "const char[] version" << std::endl;
}

template<size_t N>
void f(char(&a)[N])
{
   std::cout << "char[] version" << std::endl;
}
```

But if object is const, than `buf` and `string-literal` have equivalent types (diff can be only in symbols count, i.e. `N`) and you cannot distinguish them.

> A string literal is a sequence of characters (as defined in 2.14.3)
>   surrounded by double quotes
>
> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and has static storage duration (3.7).

Comment: Yeah, I want distinguish between const and const :(

Answer (score 0):

Building on [ForEveR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520133/5324741)
It is also worth discussing why checking for a string rvalue reference(std::is_rvalue_reference) would not work

> I try std::is_rvalue_reference but without success.

This is because string literals are in fact lvalues as stated in 5.1.1.1

> A literal is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form (2.13). A string literal is an lvalue; all other
>   literals are prvalues.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because both `foo.buf` and `"st"` have the same type: `const char[3]`.

But, you can distinguish them if you change `buf` type. This can be a practical solution.

```
struct Foo {
    std::array<char, 3> buf;
};

template<size_t N>
void f(const char(&a)[N])
{
   std::cout << "const char[N] version" << std::endl;
}

template<size_t N>
void f(const std::array<char, N>&)
{
   std::cout << "const std::array[N] version" << std::endl;
}
```